# celery, what happens to apply_async if eta is past?

Tags: celery

It's hard to debug it to find out myself.

What happens if eta is past when you call `apply_async()` ?

silently drops it? executes it because it should have been in the past?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just tested this on our setup, eta in the past definitely works.
Celery does not drop the task - It gets executed more or less immediately. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> The ETA (estimated time of arrival) lets you set a specific date and time that is the earliest time at which your task will be executed. countdown is a shortcut to set eta by seconds into the future.  The task is guaranteed to be executed at some time after the specified date and time, but not necessarily at that exact time.